# Why are these table cells not being added?

Tags: c#, .net, itext, cell

I'm trying to create a pdf report using iTextSharp and I'm stumped as to why it's not correctly going to the next row to add the cells.

Here's the code:

```
    public class Centralizador
    {
        public void PrintCentralizador(int gradeParaleloId, string gradeName, string paraleloName, string courseName)
        {
            var studentRepo = new StudentRepository();
            var students = studentRepo.FindAllStudentsFromGradeParalelo(gradeParaleloId).OrderBy(s => s.LastNameFather);
            int rowHeight = 13;
            string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\Centralizador.pdf";

            try
            {
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
                //Landscape the document.
                document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                Font font = new Font(baseFont, 8);

                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                document.Open();

                GradeParaleloRepository paraRep = new GradeParaleloRepository();
                var gra = paraRep.FindGradeParalelo(gradeParaleloId);
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Centralizador - Gestion " + DateTime.Now.Year + " \n " + courseName + " " + gra.Grade.Name + " " + gra.Name + "\n Colegio Madre Vicenta Uboldi \n " + DateTime.Now, font));
                document.Add(p);

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(36); //36 Column table.
                table.TotalWidth = 800f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                float[] widths = new float[] { 0.13f, 1.4f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f, 0.13f };
                table.SetWidths(widths);

                PdfPCell blankCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", font));
                blankCell.FixedHeight = 25;

                PdfPCell blankCellB = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", font));
                blankCellB.FixedHeight = 25;

                table.AddCell(blankCell);
                table.AddCell(blankCellB);

                PdfPCell mat = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("MAT", font));
                mat.Colspan = 3;
                mat.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(mat);

                PdfPCell len = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("LEN", font));
                len.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                len.Colspan = 3;
                table.AddCell(len);

                PdfPCell psi = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PSI", font));
                psi.Colspan = 3;
                psi.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(psi);

                PdfPCell cna = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CNA", font));
                cna.Colspan = 3;
                cna.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(cna);

                PdfPCell soc = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("SOC", font));
                soc.Colspan = 3;
                soc.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(soc);

                PdfPCell ing = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ING", font));
                ing.Colspan = 3;
                ing.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(ing);

                PdfPCell efi = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("EFI", font));
                efi.Colspan = 3;
                efi.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(efi);

                PdfPCell mus = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("MUS", font));
                mus.Colspan = 3;
                mus.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(mus);

                PdfPCell apl = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("APL", font));
                apl.Colspan = 3;
                apl.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(apl);

                PdfPCell rel = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("REL", font));
                rel.Colspan = 3;
                rel.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(rel);

                PdfPCell com = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("COM", font));
                com.Colspan = 3;
                com.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                table.AddCell(com);

                PdfPCell blankCellC = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", font));
                blankCellC.FixedHeight = 25;
                table.AddCell(blankCellC);

                //This is supposed tobe on a new row. But isn't. It seems
                //everything below this comment doesn't even get added.
                PdfPCell numero = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("No.", font));
                numero.FixedHeight = rowHeight;
                numero.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.AddCell(numero);                

                PdfPCell nombres = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Apellidos y Nombres", font));
                nombres.FixedHeight = rowHeight;
                nombres.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.AddCell(nombres);

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    PdfPCell pa = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PA.", font));
                    table.AddCell(pa);

                    PdfPCell re = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("RE.", font));
                    table.AddCell(re);

                    PdfPCell nf = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NF.", font));
                    table.AddCell(nf);
                }

                PdfPCell obs = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OBS.", font));

                table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
                table.SpacingAfter = 20f;

                document.Add(table);
                document.Close();
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(de.Message);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's a picture of how it ends up: So it add the last column com correctly, also adds the blank padding cell, then it doesn't add what comes next. It just doesn't display. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: If I add declare the PdfTable with 37 in the constructor (37 columns) and add another float to the widths array, the "No." appears. So the bug seems to be that it doesn't go down to the next row. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add exact number of columns for each row to have it shown.

See my answer for your other question [PdfTable isn't added to my document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071665/pdftable-isnt-added-to-my-document)

Comment: Amazing how this behavior isn't documented. Hopefully this helps other people with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvCalls.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Visible )
        {
            if (cell.Value != null)
                pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
            else
                pdfTable.AddCell("");
        }
        //  continue;
    }
}
```