# PdfTable isn't added to my document

Tags: c#, .net, itext

Here's the code:

```
public void PrintBoletin(int studentId, int gradeParaleloId)
{
    StudentRepository studentRepo = new StudentRepository();
    var student = studentRepo.FindStudent(studentId);
    int rowHeight = 20;

    string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\Boletin.pdf";
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font = new Font(baseFont, 8);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();

    GradeParaleloRepository paraRep = new GradeParaleloRepository();
    var gra = paraRep.FindGradeParalelo(gradeParaleloId);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Boletin de Notas - Gestion " + DateTime.Now.Year + " \n " + gra.Grade.Name + " " + gra.Name + "\n Colegio Madre Vicenta Uboldi \n " + DateTime.Now, font));
    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Alumno: " + student.StudentId + " - " + student.LastNameFather + " " + student.LastNameMother + ", " + student.Name, font));

    document.Add(p);
    document.Add(p2);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(14); //14 Column table.
    table.TotalWidth = 550f;
    float[] widths = new float[] { 1.4f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f, 0.18f };
    table.SetWidths(widths);

    PdfPCell materia = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("MATERIA", font));
    materia.Rowspan = 2;
    materia.Colspan = 2;
    materia.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    materia.VerticalAlignment = 1;
    table.AddCell(materia);


    table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
    table.SpacingAfter = 20f;

    document.Add(table);
    document.Close();

    Process.Start(filePath);
}
```

When I open the generated PDF file, no table is added to the document at all. Only the paragraphs are. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a table with 14 columns, but only add one. In `PdfPTable` you create rows by just adding cells. If number of cells added is equal to the expected column number, a row is created. So if you only add one cell, no row is created.

Furthermore, you use `ColSpan = 2`, so you only need to add 7 columns per row.

I changed `RowSpan` to 1 as it didn't work well here when all the cells were rowspanned, it didn't make sense to have it spanned anyway, so...

Here's my modification which creates a single row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < widths.Length / 2; i++)
{
    PdfPCell materia = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("MATERIA", font));
    materia.Rowspan = 1;
    materia.Colspan = 2;
    materia.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    materia.VerticalAlignment = 1;
    table.AddCell(materia);
}
```